# Array > Object: how to index an array of objects with reduce, omitting the index from nested element in result (es2017)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, ecmascript-2017

I have an array like this:

```
const peopleArray = [
    {
        "id": "Antoine",
        "country": "France"
    },
    {
        "id": "Alejandro",
        "country": "Spain"
    }
]
```

That I would like to represent as on object like this (note that id is not a property):

```
{
    "Antoine": {
        "country": "France"

    },
    "Alejandro": {
        "country": "Spain"
    }
}
```

So far I've found I can do this (elegant!):

```
peopleArray.reduce( (ac, p) => ({...ac, [p.id]: p }), {} )
```

Which produces:

```
{
    "Antoine": {
        "id": "Antoine",
        "country": "France"

    },
    "Alejandro": {
        "id": "Alejandro",
        "country": "Spain"
    }
}
```

I'm at a loss of how to accomplish the same in a terse/elegant way such that `id` is omitted.

Looking for a pure javascript es2017 solution that works with Node.js version 8.11.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make and object with `id` as key and remaining object as `value`. You can try following using [Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

**ES2017**

```js
const peopleArray = [{"id": "Antoine","country": "France"},{"id": "Alejandro","country": "Spain"}];

const result = peopleArray.reduce( (ac, o) => { 
  ac[o.id] = Object.assign({}, o); 
  delete ac[o.id].id; 
  return ac; 
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

**ES2018** - Will be able to use Rest Parameters for objects

```js
const peopleArray = [{"id": "Antoine","country": "France"},{"id": "Alejandro","country": "Spain"}];

const result = peopleArray.reduce( (ac, {id, ...rest}) => Object.assign(ac, {[id]: rest}), {} );
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Object destructuring the parameter is definitely the way to go. Good answer!

Comment: @FrankerZ - Thanks mate!

Comment: @FrankerZ you are absolutely right, this is the correct solution.

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal Sorry, I submitted my comment before it was finished and you may have read it before I included a reference link. Array rest/spread was es2015 but object rest/spread is es2018.  https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread --and-- https://node.green/#ES2018-features-object-rest-spread-properties-object-rest-properties

Comment: @Ville - My bad. Then for only 1 property you can try following `const result = peopleArray.reduce( (ac, o) => Object.assign(ac, {[o.id]: {country : o.country}}), {});`

Comment: And for more properties, `const result = peopleArray.reduce( (ac, o) => {
ac[o.id] = Object.assign({}, o);
delete ac[o.id].id;
return ac;
}, {} );`

Answer (score 0):

You can do :
`peopleArray.reduce( (ac, p) => ({...ac, [p.id]: { country : p.country } }), {} )`